# Post https by wininet c++ in win xp, 7 and 8

Tags: c++, https, wininet

My app create post request to my server in https 443 port its run correctly in win 10 but doesn't run in older than windows version.

My code run correctly previously but the company host refresh his hosts and disabled TLS 1.0, that Wininet 0depends it in Microsoft Explorer.

How can I dealing post https in Windows 7 , 8 , and 8.1 by Wininet.

Note: - host doesn't run in Microsoft explorer but it run in Chrome.

```
BOOL isSend = HttpSendRequestA(request, header, headerlen, data, datalen);
if (!isSend) {
     DWORD ErrorNum = GetLastError();
     std::cout << "Failed to open URL \nError No: " << ErrorNum << std::endl; 
}
```

Its return 12029 and 12157.

Comment: XP of course is End-of-Life; it doesn't get updates. That very much means it does not have up-to-date security. You don't need to deal with that. Windows 7 and later will need updates to have modern cyphers. [Vista and later support TLS 1.2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2011/10/02/support-for-ssltls-protocols-on-windows/)

Comment: I understand it for Windows XP, How can enable TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 by code c++ without administrator role not manual.

Comment: Did you read the link? It states how to enable TLS 1.2. Yes, you need to be Administrator, or at least have equivalent permissions. That is to be expected when you're making changes to system components like Wininet.